# Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to android development and I was following the instructions on this site:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I was trying to create my AVD but ran into this issue and could not resolve it. Google searching didn't really help either. This is the following error when I'm trying to install some of the packages:

```
Downloading SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3
Download interrupted: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
Downloading Android Support Repository, revision 6
Download interrupted: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 87: create
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API L, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android L Preview, revision 3' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Could anyone lead me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this problem!

1. run cmd.exe as admin
2. type netsh winsock reset
3. restart computer

After I did these steps, I no longer had this error.